# multiple instances of jquery tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have a total of 4 graphical buttons that I need to program tool tips to.  They will only work 1 at a time which is how they should work, and I need to be able to style all 4 individually based on size/color/position etc.

```
var id = "#tt";
var $elem = $(id);

$elem.on("mouseenter", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$elem.tooltip({
  items: id,
  content: "<div class='tooltip'><span class='title'>EMPEROR'S ELITE WASH - $18</span><br /><br /><em>Includes:</em><br />&bull; Simoniz Hot Wax and Shine</div>"
});

$elem.on("click", function(e) {

  $elem.tooltip("open");
});


$elem.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});


$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".ui-tooltip");
  if (!container.is(e.target) &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $elem.tooltip("close");
  }
});
```

Here is a fiddle I started working with: http://jsfiddle.net/c6wa4un8/261/

It worked ok as a single ID, but now I'm having trouble working with multiple elements.  Maybe there is an easier way than copying all the same code again (code above), but I just need the ability to add in separate content for each ID.

After `var container = $(".ui-tooltip")` I tried adding `.addClass( "king" );` but didn't have any luck styling that individual div.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Give the complex content, you might better off simply hiding the related items, already styled to appear in the correct place, and simply reveal them on mouseenter etc. Trying to use jQUery tooltip, just because it exists, is not always the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'll look into setting 4 divs with some .hide / .show parameters with different actions.  I recently did some onclick tabs for another project, so maybe I can adapt something from that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this since there were 4 elements I was working with.

```
$('.king').on('click', function() {
$parent_box = $(this).closest('.box');
$parent_box.siblings().find('.bottom-king').hide();
$parent_box.find('.bottom-king') .toggle();
});
```

and in the popup I coded a link to close the box

```
$('.close').on("click", function () {
$(this).parents('.bottom-king').fadeOut();  
});
```